# Store and Use HttpResponse in variable from AsyncTask into MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

How to Store and Use HttpResponse in variable from AsyncTask into MainActivity?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the 'onPostExecute' callback to receive the async result of your doInBackground.

Read here for info:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

The onPostExecute runs on the UI thread so it can interact with your UI elements, such as your buttons and EditText.

Comment: I want to store it in variable and access in main activity. is that possible?

Comment: Yes it is. For that you can use Shared preference or you can make that variable public static and access in your main activity.

Comment: Run your asynctask and set the result of the onPostExecute into your variable.

Answer (score 0):

Add Post execute method in your async task

```
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       Log.d("RESULT", "Result : " + result);
       finalResult = result; // here finalResult is string variable declared at class level

 }
```

Add one other method that is return final result of async task.

```
  public String getFinalResult() {
        return finalResult;
  }
```

When you need final result you can use getFinalResult method to get.

Comment: It returns null. Any other way?

Comment: when you are call this method??